# How does the contributor login in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I added a contributor on an app service plan, but when he logs in to azure, there is no link or anything to my app service plan.

Answer (score 1):

Once your friend has logged into portal.azure.com, if you click on the top right section where your username is, a dropdown mean will appear where your azure directory will be at. He then has to click on it to be able to see the resource group.

If you dont see it then please check the user permission on the resourcegroup and make sure you have added him correctly.

Comment: It's actually not the subscription you'll see in that menu, but the *directory*. Once you pick the right directory, you can then access the relevant subscriptions.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Thanks, I always called it the subscription just because it has the subscriptions email on it.